# Create conditional bash script code

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I use the following code to load some text file with emails
and create users in the system with user password.
the text file contain emails like following

```
abc@gmail.com
BDD@gmail.com
ZZZ@gmail.com
```

In case the name is coming with upper case I convert it to lower case, I was able to make it work. 
Now I need to support another input instead of email
e.g.

```
P123456
Z877777
```

but now I dont want for this type of input to convert it to lower case

someting like

```
if(emailpattern )
  convert to lower
else
  Not
```

This is the code which works but I failed to make it work...

```
for user in $(cat ${users} | awk -F";" '{ print $1 }'); do
    user=$(echo ${user} | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
    log "cf create-user ${user} ${passwd}"
    #Here we are creating email user in the sys
    cf create-user ${user} ${passwd} 2>&1 |
    tee -a ${dir}/${scriptname}.log ||
    { log "ERROR cf create-user ${user} failed" ;
    errorcount=$[errorcount + 1]; }
done
```

Comment: A few things not clear (to me) ... do you have a mix of email addresses and names (eg, `P123456`) in the same file?  what is the value of `${users}` in your sample code?  where is `${password}` coming from?  what are the actual (bash) commands you want to generate for the various types of input data?

Comment: @markp - It can be mixed but can be just email or just name ..., users is the contenct of the file , password is a constant

Comment: @john, please note that `${user}` is very different from `"$user"` -- [you want to use the latter syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
while IFS= read -r user; do
    # convert to lowercase only when $user has @ character
    [[ $user == *@* ]] && user=$(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<< "$user")

    log "cf create-user ${user} ${passwd}"

    cf create-user ${user} ${passwd} 2>&1 |
    tee -a ${dir}/${scriptname}.log ||
    { log "ERROR cf create-user ${user} failed" ;
    errorcount=$[errorcount + 1]; }

done < <(awk -F ';' '{ print $1 }' "$users")
```

Comment: Thanks , I've tried it and I got error `awk: can't open file users` , any idea?

Comment: Try it now. Sorry filename should be: `"$users"`

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- input file consists of email addresses or names, each on a separate line
- email addresses are to be converted to lower case
- names are to be left as is (ie, no conversion to lower case)
- all of the `log/cf/tee/errorcount` code functions as desired

Sample input file:

```
$ cat userlist
abc@gmail.com
BDD@gmail.com
ZZZ@gmail.com
P123456
Z877777
```

We'll start by using `awk` to conditionally convert email addresses to lower case:

```
$ awk '/@/ {$1=tolower($1)} 1' userlist
abc@gmail.com
bdd@gmail.com
zzz@gmail.com
P123456
Z877777
```

- first we'll run the input file (`userlist`) through `awk` ...
- `/@/` : for lines that include an email address (ie, contains `@`) ...
- `$1=tolower($1)` : convert the email address (field #1) to all lowercase, then ...
- `1` : true for all records and implies `print` all inputs to output

Now pipe the `awk` output to a `while` loop to perform the rest of the operations:

```
awk '/@/ {$1=tolower($1} 1}' userlist | while read user
do
    log "cf create-user ${user} ${passwd}"
    #Here we are creating email user in the sys
    cf create-user ${user} ${passwd} 2>&1 | 
    tee -a ${dir}/${scriptname}.log ||
    { log "ERROR cf create-user ${user} failed" ;
      errorcount=$((errorcount + 1)) ;
    }
done
```

- updated to correctly increment errorcount by 1

Answer (score 1):

bash [can lower-case text](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ $line == *@* ]] && line=${line,,}
    # do stuff with "$line"
done
```